# Twitter Exception seen during Twitter Salesforce integration (login using twitter credentials)

Tags: apex, integration

I am using the following site to install twitter API. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_TwitterForce. I install the twitter API on eclipse. While testing the API using the page : https://na7.salesforce.com/apex/twitter , on giving my credentials I get the following error. [image]

The credentials are perfectly correct. I checked with multiple accounts but I still get the error. Is there a change in the API? Anyone getting this exception. Help needed!

Comment: User1837854 (have you considered updating this?) - i've taken the liberty to update your question tags to "apex" and "integration". Please try to use tags related to the subject of your question, this doesn't appear to be the case with the tags you had selected. If i've changed this in error, do please update your question to reflext why it is related to CRM, Communities or the Salesforce1-App.

Answer (score 1):

This is logged as an issue on the codeshare since 2009 :

https://code.google.com/p/twitterforce/issues/detail?id=1

The code share for this was produced more than 5 years ago, and twitter have changed their APIs a number of times since then, so its highly likely to be out of date.